# How can this directional fade in be achieved in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-design, android-jetpack

[image]

This seems to be 2 Compose views overlaying than 1 being faded out from top left direction. How can directional fading be achieved in jetpack compose?